# Best way to setup a .deb & .rpm repository on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, repository, yum

I'm relatively inexperienced with Linux, other than the basics. But my company have asked me to find a way to setup a repository hosted on Ubuntu for rpm & and deb packages. Now I've finally managed to get a public apt repository working for the deb packages, but cannot work out a way to do it for RPM packages. especially since Createrepo is no longer being distributed for Ubuntu 20.04.

Some suggestions I've seen are to just setup a VM of Fedora etc and make the repository there, then just copy the files over to ubuntu. But Would that work? is there a better way to do it?

We've considered using a package hoster but my employer would still prefer that we host them ourselves. at least for now.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Apologies @guiverc I did mean 20.04. My mistake

Comment: @Rinzwind its required for clients who aren't using ubuntu. We're just hosting it there. But the packages are for a variety of OS's. RHEL/CENTOS, Raspbian etc.

Comment: Ok valid reason but do that then from a redhat server. Or set it up such that you can create DEB packages using `alien` . Using rpm in Ubuntu will be a disaster. "Some suggestions I've seen are to just setup a VM of Fedora etc and make the repository there, then just copy the files over to ubuntu. " this sort of: don't copy them to Ubuntu; connect the redhat systems to this VM so they directly update through that repository.

Comment: @Rinzwind thank you, Maybe I'll end up building it on CentOS for both. We'll see what happens.

Comment: I'm trying to build the repos on a CI. Currently, I can still specify Ubuntu 18.04 as the host but at some point, this will change and we'll need a better solution. Any ideas what to do?
Also, I suggest using Ubuntu 18.04 that has the createrepo package

Answer (score 0):

I too was bitten by the unavailability of createrepo(-c) on Ubuntu 20.04.  I think the old `createrepo` tool used to be available and got removed, because it was installed prior to upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.2. Anyway, the solution I chose to pursue was to package it for GNU Guix, a distribution agnostic package manager. Provided you have it installed (see: https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Installation.html) and up-to-date (using `guix pull`), you should be able to:

```
$ guix install createrepo-c
[...]
$ createrepo_c --version
Version: 0.17.4 (Features: LegacyWeakdeps )
```

On top of Ubuntu 20.04, or any other GNU/Linux distribution for what it's worth.